# By or with - machines and tools

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know which preposition should be used with machines such as "dug by/with excavator(s)", "moved by/with crane(s)". I tried a Google search in the "co.uk" segment, but the usage varies from site to site. If "by" is better than "with", why? We say "dig with a shovel", and not "by".

Comment: The main difference between driving an excavator and digging with a shovel is that the exacavator's engine provides the physical force to do the job and the driver controls its action while the physical force required to dig the hole with a shovel is provided by the operator's muscles (actually holes are dug with spades, shovels are used to move piles of materials such as gravel but that's being a little pedantic). This means that people dig _with_ spades but we can consider that the excavation is done _by_ the excavator in a very real sense. The same thing applies to cranes, of course.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. Though some English sites use "with cranes/excavators" too.

Comment: *The hole was dug by an excavator* is a passive voice construction for *An excavator dug the hole*. *The hole was dug with an excavator* is a passive voice construction for *[Someone] dug the hole with an excavator*. So it depends on what you're trying to express.

Comment: "by" is usually followed by the actor, while "with" is followed by the tool that the actor used, e.g. "The nail was driven with a hammer by the carpenter." But in some cases we anthropomorphize tools, usually large tools that seem to have some agency (like excavators and back-hoes).

Comment: And if the tool works automatically without an operator, it will be anthropomorphized.

Comment: @Georgee It's perfectly reasonable to say that the driver is _using_ the excavator to dig the hole as well as saying that the excavator is digging the hole. However it is not reasonable to say that the spade has dug the hole because it has no power to do it without the muscles of the operator. You could only say that the spade dug the hole if you were writing about something like an enchanted spade or an anthopomorphosed spade in a fantasy story of some sort. The broom in the Disney short "The Sorcerer's Apprentice" could be described as cleaning the room for example.